# "He sits on a chair" Is 'sit' transitive or intransitive?

Tags: grammar

> He sits on a chair

Is 'sit' transitive or intransitive in this case?
I think it's transitive since the object is chair.

Comment: It's intransitive in your example. See an explanation of the transitive and intransitive uses of **sit** at: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sit

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not transitive in that context. "chair" is part of a prepositional clause that indicates where he sits.

You can check [this link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sit) from Oxford Learners Dictionary with multiple examples of both the transitive and the intransitive modes but let me quote the definitions:

[intransitive]

> to rest your weight on your bottom with your back vertical, for
>   example on/in a chair 
> *She sat and stared at the letter in front of
>   her.*

[transitive]

> sit **somebody** + adv./prep. 
> to put somebody in a sitting position
>  *He
>   lifted the child and sat her on the wall.*

Notice that sit is transitive when the subject executes the action over **somebody else**, a different person.

He sit **her child** on the chair.

He - subject
her child - object

In your example he sits "himself", that "himself" is a sort of omitted and redundant object, and as you can read in the above definition, that mode is considered **intransitive**.